# How to perform selectors with an argument?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, selector

How do you perform selectors with an argument? This is my code:

```
SEL methods=NSSelectorFromString([arrayWithMethods objectAtIndex:i]);
[self performSelector:methods withObject:self afterDelay:MAN_SPEED*i];
```

If my selector method has an argument, how do I specify it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string for a selector with zero arguments looks like this:

```
arrayWithMethods = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"myMethod", ... nil]
```

If it has one parameter, specify that by adding a colon after the method name:

```
arrayWithMethods = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"myMethod:", ... nil]
```

Now your myMethod will get passed 'self' (since that's what you're passing as the 'with object".

Answer (score 4):

If it has only one argument you can pass it with the parameter `withObject:`

if it has more than 1 argument, your going to need a wrapper object to pass it with the same parameter.

Comment: alternatively use NSInvocation

Comment: There's [`performSelector:withObject:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCGGCBE) for two-parameter methods.